# Xamarin Forms: Android - No suitable method found to override OnElementChanged()

Tags: c#, android, google-maps, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am writing a Xamarin Forms application which shows a polygon of latitude/longitude coordinates on a map. I am going through [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/polygon-map-overlay/) Xamarin tutorial for adding a custom renderer for a polygon overlay on a map.

I have created a class in my Android project called `CustomMapRenderer.cs` which inherets from Android's `MapRenderer` class. In this class I am trying to override the `OnElementChanged` method but I am running into an error

**1)** `CustomMapRenderer.OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<View>)': no suitable method found to override`.

**2)** `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.View> to 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Map>`

I am confused because this code has not been modified from the tutorial linked above.

Here is my code:

```
using Android.Gms.Maps;
using MapOverlay.Droid;
using SafeAgSystems.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomMap), typeof(CustomMapRenderer))]
namespace MapOverlay.Droid
{ 
public class CustomMapRenderer : MapRenderer, IOnMapReadyCallback
  {
    GoogleMap map;
    List<Position> shapeCoordinates;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e) //Error 1
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e); //Error2

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            // Unsubscribe
        }

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            var formsMap = (CustomMap)e.NewElement;
            shapeCoordinates = formsMap.ShapeCoordinates;

            ((MapView)Control).GetMapAsync(this);
        }
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you inherit from [`MapRenderer`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Android/MapRenderer.cs) the method you should override is

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<Map> e)
```

Comment: This worked to make the map visible on Xamarin.Droid, but I noticed that any configuration passed from the Forms map in the PCL, such as map.MoveToRegion... is seemingly ignored, but that's not the case in Xamarin.iOS. Any insights on this?

Comment: This thread discusses the issue and provides workarounds: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/92565/android-ionmapreadycallback-forms-2-3-4#latest